# A sum of Euler products

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

Maybe someone have come across a particular sum related to Euler's product in the form:

$$S(x) = \frac{1}{5} (1 - \frac{2}{3}) + \frac{1}{7} (1 - \frac{2}{3})(1 - \frac{2}{5}) + \ ... \ = \sum_{p > 3}^{p < x} \ \frac{1}{p} \; \prod_{p_l > 1}^{p_l < p} \; (1 - \frac{2}{p_l})$$

where the sum and the products are over primes and we are interested in asymptotics at $x \to \infty$.

It is possible to approach it with estimating the products first (as $\sim \frac{1}{log^2 p_l}$) then summation over $p$ but it looks messy to keep track of the terms. Wonder if there can be alternative strategies?

Comment: $1-\frac2{p_1}=0$

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_p p^{-1} \prod_{2<q<p} (1-2/q)$ converges and $$\sum_{p> x }p^{-1} \prod_{2<q<p} (1-2/q)=\sum_{p> x }p^{-1} (C+o(1))(\log p)^{-2}$$ $$ =\sum_{n> x } (\log n)^{-1}n^{-1} (C+o(1))(\log n)^{-2}= \frac12(C+o(1)) (\log n)^{-2}$$
where $C=\lim_{x\to \infty} (\log x)^2 \prod_{2<q<x} (1-2/q)$ and $e^{2\gamma} C$ is the twin prime constant. We need the Mertens theorems.

Answer (score 0):

With some transformations, I found a solution with an exact analytical expression:

$$S(p) = \frac{1}{3} - \Pi_2(p_{pr})$$

where $p_{pr}$ is the previous prime, $\Pi_2 = \prod (1 - \frac{2}{p})$. It follows immediately from the relation between two consecutive members of the sum $N(p_{pr}), \ N(p)$ that can be obtained from the definition of the sum: $N(p) = (p_{pr} - 2) \ N(p_{pr})$.